# How to use keyof Interface with keys from Enum

Tags: typescript

For interface like this:

```js
enum Letters {
    C = 'C',
    D = 'D'
}

enum Characters {
    E = 'E',
    F = 'F'
}

interface ABC {
    A: string;
    B: string;
    [Letters.C]: string;
    [Characters.E]: string;
}
```

When I try to use `keyof ABC`:

```js
function action(key: keyof ABC) {
    console.log(key)
}
action('A'); // works
action('C'); // Argument of type '"C"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof ABC'.
action('E'); // Argument of type '"E"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof ABC'.
```

Is it possible to make it work without:

```js
function action(key: keyof ABC | keyof typeof Letters | keyof typeof Characters) {
```

[Typescript playground link here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=27&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAMsAu9gCcDOUDeAoKuoGEoBeKAcn1IBoc8ARYs20rAXyy1EgIAsBDZXgGMkaTDVwBRBqQlVxUAGLSFzNuwCWIEQDMhwKAEEAQoWx5DALiip4yTQHMA3PKNWbdkE-kBtOIhSoAHT4ALputg7O5t74fALCAYESYdYRns5qAPSZUAASAPIA6lAAKvmGAGr5AJL0JbnVAMoWWNnaYCDC6gD2IFBC8D0gABQA1sAAnlbjE93ahiZQAD5QM3NQ8BMADsDrfiLoK2vzmzvrsfwDAQCUYu2dg739Xb1jk9OT68b4t2Z4gr1UN0ADbAQLA7r2N4Ta6sLADIbDUgGUjXZwI17kVHol4jGTYrBAA)

**WORKAROUND 1:**

As Edwin suggested I will use `action(Letters.C); action(Characters.E);` as workaround

Comment: How about use it in the following way?

`action(Letters.C);`
`action(Characters.E);`

Comment: @Edwin Hm.. It would work, but sometimes I need to pass a string. I will use this workaround for now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate custom type

```
enum Letters {
    C = 'C',
    D = 'D'
}

enum Characters {
    E = 'E',
    F = 'F'
}

interface ABC {
    A: string;
    B: string;
}

type LettersAndCharacters = keyof typeof Letters | keyof typeof Characters | keyof ABC;

function action(key: LettersAndCharacters) {
    console.log(key)
}

action('A'); // works
action('C'); // Argument of type '"C"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof ABC'.
action('E'); // Argument of type '"E"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof ABC'.
```